# Variance Swap volatility

Tags: volatility, swaps, variance

In an article, it is mentioned that a parameter is "the variance swap volatility at time t".

I know what a variance swap is but I don't know what they could mean by "variance swap volatility".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would guess the value of volatility that makes the variance swap with strike equal to it have zero value.